# How many types of waits in selenium?

Tags: selenium, explicit

I am looking types for selenium waits.I know two explicit and implicit.I want to to further and more.Can any one help me to know,thanks.

Comment: The docs can and google can... what is your question?

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Then read [ask] and take a few minutes to add some details to your question, especially an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

**Implicit Wait:**  if the Web Driver cannot find it immediately because of its availability, it will keep polling (around 250 milli seconds) the DOM to get the element. If the element is not available within the specified Time an NoSuchElementException will be raised. The default setting is zero. Once we set a time, the Web Driver waits for the period of the WebDriver object instance.

**Explicit Wait:** There can be instance when a particular element takes more than a minute to load. In that case you definitely not like to set a huge time to Implicit wait, as if you do this your browser will going to wait for the same time for every element.

To avoid that situation you can simply put a separate time on the required element only. By following this your browser implicit wait time would be short for every element and it would be large for specific element.

**Fluent Wait:** Let’s say you have an element which sometime appears in just 1 second and some time it takes minutes to appear. In that case it is better to use fluent wait, as this will try to find element again and again until it find it or until

Refer this [link](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/)